# What is the meaning of $\rho \nu_{\rho}$?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08545.pdf). On page 14, section 3.1, I am trying to understand the notation $\rho \nu_{\rho}$, where $\rho$ is a supercuspidal representation $GL_n(F)$, $F$ is a non-archimedean local field with normalized absolute value $|\cdot|$, $\nu_{\rho} = |\cdot|^{s_{\rho}}$, $s_{\rho}$ is some real number. Is $\nu_{\rho}$ a representation of $GL_n(F)$? Does $\rho \nu_{\rho}$ mean the composition of two representations of $GL_n(F)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: With the p.7 it suggests $(\pi |.|^s)(a) v = |\det(a)|^s \pi(a) v$ so for $\pi_1,\pi_2$ two representations of $GL_n(R)$ and $a,b \in GL_n(R)$
let $\Pi_s(\pmatrix{a & * \\ 0 & b}) (v \otimes w )= |\det(a)|^s\pi_1(a) v \otimes \pi_2 (b)w $ then $\pi_1 |.|^s \times \pi_2 = Ind_P^{GL_{n+n}(R)} \Pi_s$ where $ P = \{ \pmatrix{a & * \\ 0 & b}, a,b \in GL_n(R)\}$